# Не работает break point и выдает -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, double, деление, breakpoint

Решаю задачу по программированию (Работа с файлами).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток 
 // ввода
   SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в 
 // поток вывода

ifstream fin("Archive.txt");//откуда считываем данные

    string name;//название файла хранения
    cin >> name;//Ввод имени файла который создаем
    string s;//переменная для хранения строк из файла
    ofstream fout(name + ".txt");
    int n;
    fin >> n;
    vector<double> vec(n);
    double in;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fin >> in;
        vec.push_back(in);
    }
    double inD;
    double inDsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i]; j++)
        {
            fin >> inD;
            inDsum += inD;
        }
        cout << inDsum / vec[i]<<endl;
        inDsum = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Надо найти среднее арифметическое (неважно чего).

но почему то выводит -nan(ind);

Попробовал в отладчике,но break point не работает на строчке:`fin >> inD;`

IDE:visual studio;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании `vector<double> vec(n);` вектор будет изначально содержать `n` нулей. Соответственно `inDsum / vec[i]` будет делением на ноль. Надо было заполнять не добавляя элементов:

```
fin >> vec[i];
```

Comment: Но я вектор заполняю .push_back()

Comment: @Apkfile Так а вот этого делать не надо.

Comment: попробую...  надеюсь сработает

Comment: @Apkfile: Что значит "заполняю"? Вы сначала создаете вектор из `n` нулей, а затем в дополнение к этим нулям (после нулей) еще набрасываете свой `push_back`. Если вы хотите заполнять вектор через `push_back`, то уберите это `n` при создании вектора. Должно быть просто `vector<double> vec;`. Никакого `n`.

Comment: AnT огромное спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Apkfile, VTT Вам сказал тоже самое. Если ответ Вам помог - отметьте его как "верный".

Comment: Ну простите,просто vtt не очень понял